# Cannot open url connection

Tags: java

I have searched and looked and I cannot seem to find the source of my problem.
I have code that is supposed to be taking a url, but for some reason no matter what I do. It seems to not be connected.

```
src = "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/410oAxun7dL._AA300_.jpg"
URL url = new URL(src);
URLConnection connection = (URLConnection) url.openConnection();
((HttpURLConnection) connection).setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.connect();
InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
```

I get a `java.net.SocketException: Permission denied` error.

What is the cause of this error? And How would I fix it?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Is that code in an Applet application?

Comment: Could you show the entire stack trace and tell us which line throws the exception? Also, as Marcelo mentions, if it's an Applet (or a Java Web Start app for that matter) that could affect it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are trying to do this code in an Applet.  That is not allowed, you will have to digitally sign your applet to get it to be allowed to access another server.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a permissions issue on the folder?  Make sure you can browse to the image via the browser.

Comment: It's an image on Amazon, at least the one in his example is. I tried it and it worked, though it's an odd image.